# How to subtract inserted value from previous rows field value for each entry in a statement

Tags: mysql, insert, subtraction

I need to do an insert into a table of each shipment that day. I am having a problem deducting the total amount from the previous row. I am inserting into tableC, but since if I have multiple orders in a day its only grabbing the last debit entry and deducting from the original last rows total. I know this is because I am using the ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1, but I can't think of another way to get the last rows total column value. I also need the second insertion to get the new total from the previous insertion.

I am using a select statement inside a variable to run inside my insert statment. **@vTotal**

If its a single entry insertion it would work, but how do I this to work if there is multiple rows in the select statement, or is there a better way to do this?

Below is my current test query:

```
SET @vCreatedbt := 'name@domain.com';
SET @vTotal := (SELECT tableC.total - tableB.ShipmentCharge AS total 
                FROM tableC, tableB 
                ORDER BY id DESC 
                LIMIT 1);
SET @vwork_order_id := null;
SET @vModified := null;
SET @vModified_by := null;
SET @vCredit := null;
SET @vid := null;

INSERT INTO tableC
    SELECT @vId AS id, client_name AS descr, @vWork_order_id AS work_order_id, 
            @vCredit AS credit, ShipmentCharge as debit, @vTotal AS total, 
            now() as created, @vCreatedby as createdby, 
            @vModified AS modified, @vModified_by AS modified_by
    FROM tblA
        INNER JOIN tableD ON tableA.id = tableD.id
        INNER JOIN tableB ON tableD.tracking_number = tableB.TrackingNumber
        WHERE tableA.status = 'Order Shipped'
```

Just showing these three fields of tableC to simplify

| id | debit | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27.37 | 15260.96 |

Query is giving me

| id | debit | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27.37 | 15260.96 |
| 2 | 25.96 | 15235.96 |
| 3 | 25.00 | 15235.96 |

The id is auto incremented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO:

```
CREATE TABLE balance (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  person_id INT NOT NULL,
  action DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  balance DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  created_at DATETIME(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  CONSTRAINT balance_cannot_be_negative CHECK (balance >= 0)
);
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_balance
BEFORE INSERT ON balance
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.balance = COALESCE(
    (
    SELECT balance 
    FROM balance
    WHERE person_id = NEW.person_id
    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    ), 0) + NEW.action;
```

```
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (1, 100); -- add $100, balance $100
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (1, -20); -- spend $20, balance $80
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (2, 50);  -- add $50, balance $50
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (1, 10);  -- add $10, balance $90
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (2, 30);  -- add $30, balance $80
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (2, -40); -- spend $40, balance $40
```

```
-- try to spend $100 which is over current balance, error generated
INSERT INTO balance (person_id, action) VALUES (2, -100);
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'balance_cannot_be_negative' is violated.
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM balance ORDER BY id;
SELECT * FROM balance ORDER BY person_id, created_at;
```

| id | person_id | action | balance | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.811375 |
| 2 | 1 | -20.00 | 80.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.817546 |
| 3 | 2 | 50.00 | 50.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.819130 |
| 4 | 1 | 10.00 | 90.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.820016 |
| 5 | 2 | 30.00 | 80.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.821140 |
| 6 | 2 | -40.00 | 40.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.822273 |

| id | person_id | action | balance | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100.00 | 100.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.811375 |
| 2 | 1 | -20.00 | 80.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.817546 |
| 4 | 1 | 10.00 | 90.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.820016 |
| 3 | 2 | 50.00 | 50.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.819130 |
| 5 | 2 | 30.00 | 80.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.821140 |
| 6 | 2 | -40.00 | 40.00 | 2023-06-08 18:05:59.822273 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xa0qVufr)

`DATETIME(6)` needed in the fiddle - common `DATETIME` does not provide needed accuracy. In practice `DATETIME` must be enough - I doubt that the person can perform two separate transactoins within a second.. or you may use not `created_at` but `id` for rows ordering.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I never used a tigger before. I see its used like a stored procedure. I assume the trigger stays until its dropped? Mine is slightly different than your example, but when i did the insert it took my inserted debit number and duplicated it in the total column instead of adding or subtracting from the previous total value on the row above. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is I don't have a field like person_id. If you removed the person_id field, how would you accomplish the same? I need it to keep a balance for the that entire field, not just for specific people.

Comment: @nthingwerks See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), paragraphs 5 and 3.

Comment: Hi @Akina, Here is my attempt.  https://dbfiddle.uk/Od_olJjC   it is working fine in fiddle, but it seems to make the incorrect calculation for total on my third insert in my dev db. The desired result should look like my fiddle, but I am getting 15,082.99 as my third total. Its taking my total from the first insert and deducting the debit 52.99 instead of deducting from insert 2. I have a third party program executing this insert which I thought might be the issue at first, but I get the same result when executing it in Workbench.